# How to make linq to sql generate out parameters in C# instead of ref

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a C# procedure that is mapped to a stored procedure have an out parameter instead of ref that is by default generated by linq to sql for OUTPUT parameter. I have found everywhere that linq to sql generates ref but is there a way to force it generate out to make it more obvious in C# that this is an output and not to initialize the variable as well?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't distinguish between pure output parameters and in/out parameters. There's no real way for Linq to SQL to know that the stored procedure will not read from the variable. So it's safer for it to map it as `ref` and force initialization.

Comment: For now I have created a wrapper methods with out parameter that handle the ref parameter inside. So for the calling code it looks like an out. I have not found a better solution so far.